# Using a Widening Operator of Boolean

Tags: .net, operators, implicit

I'm trying to box a Boolean value to share it around my code.  I'm having trouble using a Widening Operator (implicit operator in C#) to simply things.

```
Public Class CancellationToken

    Public Property IsCancelled As Boolean

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(a As CancellationToken) As Boolean
        Return a.IsCancelled
    End Operator
End Class
```

The following code works fine:

```
Sub DoIt(IsCancelled As CancellationToken)
    Do Until IsCancelled
        ...
    Loop
End Sub
```

But this block reports a compile time error: Operator 'Or' is not defined for types 'CancellationToken' and 'Boolean'.

```
Sub DoIt(IsCancelled As CancellationToken)
    Dim ContentLength As Long = ...
    Do Until IsCancelled OrElse ContentLength = 0
        ...
    Loop
End Sub
```

Clearly it's evaluated `ContentLength = 0` to a boolean.  Given `OrElse` expects a Boolean on each side, why isn't `IsCancelled` implicitly converted to a Boolean?

Creating `IsTrue`, `IsFalse`, `Or`, and `And` operators don't rectify the problem either.  I have Option Explicit and Option Strict enabled.

Comment: This code seems like you working to hard to me. Why not just use the IsCancelled public property. In this case `Do Until IsCancelled.IsCancelled` (unfortunate parameter name there)

Comment: Note that it *just works* in C#....

Comment: @ConradFrix.  Purely asthetics.  I'll probably drop back to something like `Token.IsCancelled`, but I'm curious why this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, note that it *just works* in C#. However, it is possible that *in this case* the VB compiler wants to use the `IsTrue`/`IsFalse` operators:

> Overloading the Or and IsTrue operators affects the behavior of the OrElse operator.

([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2.aspx))

So: add an [`IsTrue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93xa16x4.aspx) and `IsFalse()`, perhaps *in addition to* an `Or()` (although I'd try without the `Or()` first).

Comment: How many meaningless restrictions does VB.Net want to put on this feature?  VB.Net says: Return and parameter types of 'Public Shared Operator Or(a As CancellationToken, b As Boolean) As Boolean' must be 'CancellationToken' to be used in a 'OrElse' expression.  The next new project I start, I'm taking a crash course in C#...

Comment: Accepted on the grounds of "that it just works in C#."  :-)  The best alternative I've come up with is using `Or` instead of `OrElse` as in `IsCancelled Or ContentLength = 0`.